# With Terraform 0.12 how do I trim the IP prefix from a string like 1.1.1.1/32?

Tags: terraform

I got this var:

```
variable "ip" {
  default = "1.1.1.1/32"
}
```

In some cases I need the full prefix: `"1.1.1.1/32"` but sometimes I just need the IP without the prefix: `"1.1.1.1"`

Now 0.12 has this new function which I could use like this:

```
trimsuffix(var.ip, "/32")
```

But I don't want to hard code the prefix like that. Is there a way to remove a substring base an a regex match or even just truncate the last 3 characters from a string? I can't use substr() because it expects me to know the full string length.

### Edit

I am trying to do this with regex(), but I am not sure if Terraform supports full regex.

https://regex101.com/r/EGzxAq/1

I get an error:

```
> regex("^.+(?=\/)","11.1.1.1/32")

>
Error: Invalid escape sequence

  on <console-input> line 1:
  (source code not available)

The symbol "/" is not a valid escape sequence selector.
```

And then when I try to escape the backslash:

```
> regex("^.+(?=\\/)","11.1.1.1/32")

>
Error: Invalid function argument

  on <console-input> line 1:
  (source code not available)

Invalid value for "pattern" parameter: invalid regexp pattern: invalid or
unsupported Perl syntax in (?=.
```

Comment: What do you expect the output of `192.168.0.0/16` to yield? `192.168.0.0/16`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to truncate the prefix to remove the `/32` or any other arbitrary prefix such as `/16` then you can use the [`cidrhost` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrhost.html) instead and just specify the host number as 0 to get at the network address:

```
$ terraform console
> cidrhost("192.168.0.0/16", 0)
192.168.0.0
> cidrhost("1.1.1.1/32", 0)
1.1.1.1
```

If you wanted to use regex for this for some reason then you just want to capture the section before the `/` so `(.*)/.*` should be fine to use as a search pattern. The [`regex` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/regex.html) returns a list of capture groups so you just want the first one:

```
> regex("(.*)/.*", "192.168.0.0/16")[0]
192.168.0.0
> regex("(.*)/.*", "1.1.1.1/32")[0]
1.1.1.1
```

Comment: you cant have a variable type of cidrhost can you? there is no ip address datatype right?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you provide an example? What would you want to do with that? Just enforce that someone only enters a valid prefix in CIDR notation? You could probably do that with `can` if you really wanted but otherwise it will blow up in a reasonably readable way anyway: `Call to function "cidrhost" failed: invalid CIDR expression: invalid CIDR address: 1.1.1.1.`